# ClickOnce deployment and installation path on my PC

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I have a application that I deployed to web server. Users go to "publish.htm" deployment web page to install my vb.net application. I have a very simple question , but I can't quite figure out. Where is the application installed? I don't think it is installed under "Program Files" like others.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ClickOnce deployment is designed to have zero-impact on the host machine so ClickOnce apps are installed into user folders in order not to have any impact on the host machine and not to require admin rights.

On Vista/Win7 this location is `SysDrive:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Apps\` folder and on XP boxes I think the folder is `SysDrive:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data\` if I recall correctly.

On Vista/7 you can easily find this location buy opening Task Manager and clicking on the 'Open File Location' menu item of your application's context menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was exactly what I was wondering.

Comment: I've found for XP the folder is SysDrive:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Apps\

Answer (score 2):

It is the Application Cache, but you can select in the properties->publish->manifests to put a shortcut to the desktop automatically. The should also be a shortcut to the program in the Start->All Programs.

Comment: Is there any technical reason that Microsoft does this way for the installation? I mean use appCache folder.

Comment: The only reason I know of is to guarantee the ability to change the files in the event of an update. It is the only place the the updater will always have access to. It can be annoying though, especially when you need to install to a specific path, which is where click once is really limited.

Comment: They do this so the application will not impact the GAC or other applications installed on the machine, and those applications won't impact the ClickOnce application. The point of this is so if your customer works in an enterprise environment, they can still install your application without administrative privileges, and the system guys usually allow it because they know it can not mess up the computer.